# Having issues running turtle.py, can't seem to get the module to run properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

I'm fairly new here and still in school so apologies if this is simple but I can't seem to get turtle to work in pycharm or any other IDE. If anyone has any info please let me know.

My code:

```
#Super basic code to test turtle in pycharm
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
yertle = turtle.Turtle()
wn.exitonclick()

yertle.forward(100)
yertle.left(120)
yertle.forward(100)
```

Error after the window has closed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    yertle.forward(100)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1638, in forward
    self._go(distance)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1606, in _go
    self._goto(ende)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 3159, in _goto
    screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 756, in _pointlist
    cl = self.cv.coords(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in coords
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2762, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call the [`turtle.exitonclick()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.exitonclick) method, it's telling turtle

> *Hey, the program is over, time to allow the user to close the window by clicking.*

Now, you get the error because after the window is closed, there are some more turtle command for the program to go through, and those command need a turtle window to run on.

The fix is simple, relocate the `wn.exitonclick()` call to the bottom of your code, where you are sure that the program is over:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

yertle = turtle.Turtle()
yertle.forward(100)
yertle.left(120)
yertle.forward(100)

wn.exitonclick()
```

You need to move `wn.exitonclick()` down to the end of your script. The call doesn't return until the window is closed, so your three commands to `yertle` are being executed when it is too late to do so.